Modifying multiple files in VS Code at the same time by using the "Workspace Search Menu"
I'm currently updating an old project in which there is a lot of files.
In those files, I need to modify some lines that look slightly the same (i.e. for which I can make a regex).
I don't want to update each file one by one.
Therefore, in VS Code, I'm searching for a way to modify them at the same time.
I thought about using the "Workspace Search Menu" of VS Code in order to search the lines matching a specific regex through all my files.
Once I have found all the matching lines, I open my search result in editor mode to
modify those lines.
However, I don't know how to apply my changes to the files once I'm done.
Here is my question :
"Is it possible and if so how can I do that ?"
Btw, I am only using VS Code and I don't mind downloading some extensions if it's needed.
Note : To open the "Workspace Search Menu" you need to press Ctrl+Shift+F in Windows & Linux or Cmd+Shift+F in Mac.

Edit : I do know how to replace each occurence of a line with something else in all files using Ctrl+Shift+H (or Cmd+Shift+H).
However in my case, the changes I want to make will depend on the line.
For example :
Before the changes :

In file a.js
let a = 2;

In file b.js
let b = "Hello World !";


After the changes :

In file a.js
const a=2;

In file b.js
const b="Hello World !";


Note that the line in a.js and b.js aren't the same before nor after the changes.
However, we could say that they have been changed in the same way.

This question is similar to: How do I find and replace all occurrences (in all files) in Visual Studio Code?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Ok I will clarify this.

in the Search bar you have a button at the top: Open New Search Window

Based on your example, I don't see how the change you want to make is different from the "replace in all files" functionality. It looks like you just replaced let with const both times?

Yes, I have showed this to a friend and he told me the same thing. I guess I'm bad at finding example.
The difference was that I removed the spaces around "=" too.
Anyway, I have found a solution to my problem and will answer my own question.

when you are in Workspace Search Menu there is a small carret icon on left of search field. you can click on that to open replace field.
OR
You can invoke find and replace in all files using
Ctrl+Shift+H

thx but that's not what I needed, sorry for my lack of clarity

I found a VS Code extension that allowed me to do exactly what I wanted. This extension is simply called Search Editor: Apply Changes.
